# Why is my line not showing up? [inkscape]

Tags: inkscape

Just getting into Inkscape. When I use the pencil or "Draw Bezier lines.." buttons, I follow the instructions in the manual to get the intended effect to get a horizontal or vertical line.

Except, I cannot see the line itself. In the examples the line shows up, but after I stop highlighting it, it goes away completely. The other lines turn out fine. Below is a picture of my screen.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIc6D.png)

My opacity, and alpha are correct for the line segment (as you can see from the screenshot), so I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: same to me. spent me 30 mins to figure out that 'flat colour' was by default selected under the Fill tab. therefore it fills whatever lines you draw. what a confusing app setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a stroke instead of a fill. And make sure you are in a visible layer.

Comment: Is there any way to make a line rather than a thin rectangle in inkscape? Because that's what showed up after adjusting the stroke? Thanks for the help, again I'm just starting out.

Comment: Remove the fill, just use stroke. Then adjust the line thickness.